# How to merge a row to its closest row (based on timestamp) in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, timestamp, time-series

I am relatively new to Pandas so my sincere apologies if my question was not framed properly, I have a data set here,

```
                       t  HVAC1_S1  HVAC2_S1  ...  HVAC4_S1  HVAC5_S1  HVAC6_S1
0       2009-08-18 18:12     711.0       0.0  ...       0.0       0.0       0.0
1       2009-08-18 18:14     705.0     734.0  ...       0.0     725.0     711.0
2       2009-08-18 18:15       0.0       0.0  ...     730.0       0.0       0.0
3       2009-08-18 18:29       0.0     721.0  ...     716.0     718.0     712.0
4       2009-08-18 18:30     705.0       0.0  ...       0.0       0.0       0.0
                 ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...
156033  2012-11-09 21:59     714.0     720.0  ...     739.0       0.0     727.0
156034  2012-11-09 22:00       0.0       0.0  ...       0.0     743.0       0.0
156035  2012-11-09 22:14     723.0     729.0  ...     734.0     743.0     732.0
156036  2012-11-09 22:29     718.0     732.0  ...       0.0     739.0     725.0
156037  2012-11-09 22:30       0.0       0.0  ...     739.0       0.0       0.0
```

So if you notice the timestamp, for example, the index '1' i.e. at 2009-08-18 18:14 there were 5 readings taken (one is not visible because of ...). Now actually there are 6 readings in total but last reading was taken at the next minute i.e. at 2009-08-18 18:15. Well, it is a bit confusing because there are no seconds here. Moreover, all the 6 readings are taken at a time and then after 15 minutes they are measured again. Now while measuring one value often gets measured at the next minute because of which it is in a new row.

I want to set a tolerance of 1 minute and merge the value of such rows (like at index 2,4, 156034, 156037) to its previous rows and delete that row from data frame

so for e.g. I would like to obtain my dataframe as,

```
                       t  HVAC1_S1  HVAC2_S1  ...  HVAC4_S1  HVAC5_S1  HVAC6_S1
0       2009-08-18 18:12     711.0       0.0  ...       0.0       0.0       0.0
1       2009-08-18 18:14     705.0     734.0  ...      730.0     725.0     711.0
2       2009-08-18 18:29     705.0     721.0  ...     716.0     718.0     712.0
                 ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...
156033  2012-11-09 21:59     714.0     720.0  ...     739.0     743.0     727.0
156035  2012-11-09 22:14     723.0     729.0  ...     734.0     743.0     732.0
156036  2012-11-09 22:29     718.0     732.0  ...     739.0     739.0     725.0
```

Note: index 0 can be neglected because it is out of the 1 min tolerance.

please provide your valuable suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `asof` merge to merge the DataFrame with itself. Pick the forward direction, and do not allow exact matches (else the same row would always merge with itself). We can specify a tolerance of 1 minute. We need to bring the index along in the merge so we can remove rows that merged with others after the merge.

After the merge we'll have `_x` and `_y` columns we can remove those and group along the columns axis to combine them.

#### Input Data:

```
                    t  HVAC1_S1  HVAC2_S1  HVAC4_S1  HVAC5_S1  HVAC6_S1
0 2009-08-18 18:12:00     711.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
1 2009-08-18 18:14:00     705.0     734.0       0.0     725.0     711.0
2 2009-08-18 18:15:00       0.0       0.0     730.0       0.0       0.0
3 2009-08-18 18:29:00       0.0     721.0     716.0     718.0     712.0
4 2009-08-18 18:30:00     705.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
```

#### Code:

```
import pandas as pd
#df['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'])  #If not datetime

res = pd.merge_asof(df.reset_index(), df.reset_index(), 
                    on='t', 
                    direction='forward', 
                    allow_exact_matches=False,
                    tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1min'))
res = res.set_index('t')

res = res[~res.index_x.isin(res.index_y)]  #Remove rows that merged with others
res = res.drop(columns=['index_x', 'index_y'])

res = res.groupby(res.columns.str.rsplit('_', n=1).str[0], axis=1).sum()
```

#### Output:

```
                     HVAC1_S1  HVAC2_S1  HVAC4_S1  HVAC5_S1  HVAC6_S1
t                                                                    
2009-08-18 18:12:00     711.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
2009-08-18 18:14:00     705.0     734.0     730.0     725.0     711.0
2009-08-18 18:29:00     705.0     721.0     716.0     718.0     712.0
```

Comment: Hi Thank you, for your answer but I get an error "MergeError: key must be integer, timestamp or float" . can you please explain where I am being wrong?

Comment: @MurtazaBasu Oh you must have string keys. Before doing this try `df['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'])` so that pandas recognizes them as dates.